# The Practice of Programming

Tags: code-golf

At 1998, Brian Kernighan, while working on the book "The Practice of Programming", wanted to demonstrate realisation of regular expression engine. But struggled to find *small* engine, that cod could fit in the book.

So Brian Kernighan asked Rob Pike to write one for him, and Rob [did it](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/spr09/cos333/beautiful.html) gracefully. Here is original source:

```
    /* match: search for regexp anywhere in text */
    int match(char *regexp, char *text)
    {
        if (regexp[0] == '^')
            return matchhere(regexp+1, text);
        do {    /* must look even if string is empty */
            if (matchhere(regexp, text))
                return 1;
        } while (*text++ != '\0');
        return 0;
    }

    /* matchhere: search for regexp at beginning of text */
    int matchhere(char *regexp, char *text)
    {
        if (regexp[0] == '\0')
            return 1;
        if (regexp[1] == '*')
            return matchstar(regexp[0], regexp+2, text);
        if (regexp[0] == '$' && regexp[1] == '\0')
            return *text == '\0';
        if (*text!='\0' && (regexp[0]=='.' || regexp[0]==*text))
            return matchhere(regexp+1, text+1);
        return 0;
    }

    /* matchstar: search for c*regexp at beginning of text */
    int matchstar(int c, char *regexp, char *text)
    {
        do {    /* a * matches zero or more instances */
            if (matchhere(regexp, text))
                return 1;
        } while (*text != '\0' && (*text++ == c || c == '.'));
        return 0;
    }
```

## Rules

- Write regex engine that supports the same operations, as Rob's:

  - Any char (as symbol)
  - `.` to match any char
  - `^` to match start of the string
  - `$` to match end of the string
  - `*` to match any count of char from zero
- Auxiliary code do not count (to accept input, for example)
- Make the shortest solution and beat Rob Pike!

### Input

Two strings: one for regex, one for match.

### Output

- `True` (in your language), if regex matches string
- `False` (in your language), if regex do not match string

Comment: @Abigail You right, my typo. Edited post

Comment: What is the range of `any char`? Is it any character apart from the special characters?

Comment: Related: [Match strings with wildcards](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/59116/194), [Regular expression parser](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/125708/194), [Compile regexes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/7024/194). (Also note that this set of features falls short of truly being a regex engine: there are regular languages which it can't match).

Comment: @KrzysztofSzewczyk edited

Comment: What does `Any char (as symbol)` mean?

Comment: @JoKing just any char, that can be passed to program. `a` `b` `c` ... `@` and so on. You did much better and included character sets support, i'm impressed

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 39 bytes

```perl6
->\a{&{?/<{a}>/}}o{S:g/<-[.*$^]>/'$/'/}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcexDoIwEADQvV9xwwVaYrnNQbF8hCNCcpWeMUEhMJGm3141Ti9vCet0zK8dCoFLtu7GsYgtNZGTo5TmeD09qLFdXeHQOyqRSkpZ5hX09HyHzYB1yAf0EBXAxjuIRjYavTmrlAf297oSVF/HID@6sf/3Aw)

Simply evaluates the input as a regex, adding quotes to avoid any special characters Perl 6 uses. This takes input curried, as `f(regex)(string)`, though it could be a *lot* shorter if I can just return a regex object.

Comment: Reason for downvote?

Comment: Fails for [this](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPu/Wt@mWiW@1k6/9n9xYqWCUmJSspJCXZ1CmoZ6XGJ0UqyeirrmfwA)

Comment: Oh, didn't see your comment. I'm not the downvoter.

Comment: Oh okay. I'm not sure what chars are valid as matching, since clearly some are not meant to be matched literally

Comment: Well, rules say `.`, `^`, `$` and `*` should be special (with usual meaning), and everything else is literal.

Comment: It says `any char` is itself, then contradicts itself with the special characters. I don't see any rules about special characters in regards to the any characters. It *is* implied by the reference program, but that's about it. I have fixed my program to work like that though